Some apps won't follow system app titlebar theme in Wayland in Ubuntu 24.04.1
Some apps like qBittorrent or Okular won't follow system's own titlebar theme in an Ubuntu 24.04.1 system running on Wayland. It works in Xorg, but not in Wayland.
qBittorrent:

Okular:

This happens in both snap and apt packages. Is there any particular reason for this, and how can we fix it?
